# Link souce folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developping a Java project with Eclipse, using 2 source folders. Is there a way to link them? 
If I write in the class file "import source_folder_1.package.class", Eclipse indicates the error "the import source_folder_1 cannot be resolved"
Could you please help me?
Thanke
Eduard

Comment: could you update the picture of your project structure in eclipse?

Comment: why don't you use different packages instead of 2 sourcefolders? and as @VNT said, could you show us the current project structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source folder names are not part of package names.
The package names are formed from the directory elements below the source folder. For example if you have this directory layout in your project:

```
.
├── other-src
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           ├── client
│           └── demo
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── org
                └── uni
                    ├── api
                    └── util
```

And in Eclipse you have configured `src/main/java` and `other-src` as source directories, then you will have Java packages:

- `com.example.client`
- `com.example.demo`
- `org.uni.api`
- `org.uni.util`

The classes in whichever package will be able to `import` any of these packages, since Eclipse will find them in the two configured source folders.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave me a concise solution that works

Answer (score 0):

Just use `import thepackage.TheClass;`.

It doesn't matter if you have one or to source folders, and which of them contains the class you import. When you need to use a class by its simple name, you add an import statement with the flly qualified class name, which is the package followed by the simple class name.

Eclipse will just look in the source folders and in the libraries in the build path to find it.